# Finding the Path of all Edges on a Graph

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory, networkx

I'm trying to get the path on a graph which covers all edges, and traverses them only once. 
This means there will only be two "end" points - which will have an odd-number of attached nodes. These end points would either have one connecting edge, or be part of a loop and have 3 connections.

So in the simple case below I need to traverse the nodes in this order 1-2-3-4-5 (or 5-4-3-2-1):

[image: simple]

In the more complicated case below the path would be 1-2-3-4-2 (or 1-2-4-3-2):

[image: --graph]

Below is also a valid graph, with 2 end-points: 1-2-4-3-2-5

[image: complex]

I've tried to find the name of an algorithm to solve this, and thought it was the "Chinese Postman Problem", but implementing this based on code at https://github.com/rkistner/chinese-postman/blob/master/postman.py didn't provide the results I expected.

The Eulerian path looks almost what is needed, but the [networkx implementation](https://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.euler.eulerian_circuit.html#networkx.algorithms.euler.eulerian_circuit) will only work for closed (looped) networks.

I also looked at a [Hamiltonian Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) - and tried the [networkx algorithm](https://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.tournament.hamiltonian_path.html#networkx.algorithms.tournament.hamiltonian_path) - but the graph types were not supported.

Ideally I'd like to use Python and networkx to implement this, and there may be a simple solution that is already part of the library, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Hamiltonian Path covers all vertices, you might want to check [Eulerian Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) which covers the edges instead. GeeksForGeeks seem to have example implementation for [Python](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fleurys-algorithm-for-printing-eulerian-path/).

Comment: @niemmi - thanks! Looks like Eulerian trai (rather than circuit) is the term I am looking for. I'll take a look at the algorithm and see if it can be simplified using existing networkx methods.

Comment: @niemmi Your right you could make that into an answer as well by adding the appropriate links..

Comment: This is known as the [Eulerian Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) of a graph. It has now been added to `networkx` as [`eulerian_path()`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.euler.eulerian_path.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [Eulerian Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) that visits every edge exactly once. You can use [Fleury's algorithm](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fleurys-algorithm-for-printing-eulerian-path/) to generate the path. Fleury's algorithm has **O(E^2)** time complexity, if you need more efficient algorithm check [Hierholzer's algorithm](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hierholzers-algorithm-directed-graph/) which is **O(E)** instead.

There is also an [unmerged pull request](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/pull/1878) for the networkx library that implements this. The [source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/humberto-ortiz/networkx/eulerpath/networkx/algorithms/euler.py) is easy to use.

(For networkx 1.11 the `.edge` has to be replaced with `.edge_iter`).

Comment: Once I was sure of the name of the path type I was looking for I could find an implementation in networkx

Comment: Note: said pull request has been closed since there is a [fundamental issue](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/pull/1878#issuecomment-391931336) with the path-finding algorithm implementation in it.

Comment: @niemmi Why isnt the time complexity of Hierholzer's algorithm  O(V+E)?

Comment: @African_king Because algorithm doesn't have to care about vertices which have degree of 0. In other words, in order to walk the path of N edges, you have to visit N+1 vertices. The starting point of the algorithm can be found by picking a random edge and choosing one of its' vertices instead of iterating over vertices to find one with degree > 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as the [Eulerian Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) of a graph. It has now been added to NetworkX as [`eulerian_path()`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.euler.eulerian_path.html).